# Simulate an event to get mouse coordinates?

Tags: javascript

I need to get mouse coordinate at the moment the setTimeout function calls the provided function.

Comment: Mouse coordinates of *what*, exactly?

Comment: @Robusto: I think the OP means just "the coordinates of the mouse"

Comment: Yes, the coords of the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a `mousemove` event handler to keep track of the mouse's coordinates in a scope that's accessible by your `setTimeout()` callback. Then, your `setTimeout()` callback can just check the values you've stored from the `mousemove` handler.

At a high level, it would look something like this (**pseudocode**):

```
var mouseX, mouseY;
document.addListener('onMouseMove', function (event)
{
    mouseX = event.getMouseX(); // in reasonable browsers, this would be
    mouseY = event.getMouseY(); // event.pageX and event.pageY
});

// then, when you want to retrieve it later...
setTimeout(function ()
{
    console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
}, 1000);
```

Personally, I'd recommend using a third-party library such as jQuery, YUI, Dojo, etc. to smooth out all the cross-browser differences in event handling, if you're not doing so already.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with `setTimeout` would be problematic, because you'd have no event object to work with.  You could, however, handle "mousemove" on the `<body>` and keep track that way. The event object passed to the handler (or, in the case of IE, set up globally) will have the *x, y* coordinates of the mouse at the time the event occurred.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValues()
{
    var s = 'X=' + window.event.clientX +  ' Y=' + window.event.clientY ;
    return s;

}  

setTimeout ( getValues, 10000);
```

Comment: window.event only exists in IE and ooollld Netscape, and still is only set while running an event handler.